# Building external code trees with SCons

Tags: c++, c, build, scons

I'm trying to use SCons for building a piece of software that depends on a library that is available in sources that are installed in system. For example in `/usr/share/somewhere/src`. `*.cpp` in that directory should be built into static library and linked with my own code. Library sources have no `SConscript` among them.

Since library is in system directory I have no rights and don't want to put build artefacts somewhere under `/usr`. `/tmp` or `.build` in current working directory is OK. I suspect this can be done easily but I've got entangled by all these `SConscripts` and `VariantDirs`.

```
env = Environment()
my_things = env.SConscript('src/SConsctipt', variant_dir='.build/my_things')
sys_lib = env.SConscript(????)
result = env.Program('result', [my_things, sys_lib])
```

What is intended way to solve the problem with SCons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [Repository](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.3.0/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-repositories) to do this. For example, in your SConstruct you could write:

```
sys_lib = env.SConscript("external.scons", variant_dir=".build/external")
```

Then in the `external.scons` file (which is in your source tree), you add the path to the external source tree and how to build the library therein.

```
env = Environment()
env.Repository("/usr/share/somewhere/src")
lib = env.Library("library_name", Glob("*.cpp"))
Return("lib")
```

Comment: Looks like Repositories are just what I need. I thought they are related to VCS somehow. Bad name :)